# mysql command not working in DB visualizer

Tags: mysql

i was trying to execute the use dbname statement. In this case, i wrote the statement, `use practice`. where practice stands for the database name.

It worked with the mysql remote command, and i was notified `database changed`. 
However, when i did the same thing on DB Visualizer, i was given `[Error Code: 900, SQL State: 42000]  ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement.`
Can anyone explain why the statement works in remote command, but not on DBVisualizer?

Comment: The error is ORA-00900 which is an Oracle error code. Are you running the use <database> command in MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: yes i am running the database command in MySql. i asked around my coworker, who told me it was not correct.